# Is there an Eclipse plugin that can show a history of recent editing in my programs?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there an Eclipse plugin that can show me a history of recent editing in my programs? Sort of reminders of what and where the editing last time have been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has a built-in "Local History" feature. If you right click on a file, there should be a "Show Local History" option. You can also diff between local versions and revert changes. I believe that there is a rolling window of changes, so you may not be able to go to the beginning of time. It also only shows local changes, not changes made by other developers.

If you're using a version control system (which you should be), most version control systems maintain file history and Eclipse often integrates with this functionality to compare or revert files. However, the functionality and specific implementation of this depends on the version control system and Eclipse plugin for the system that you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I will look for a version control plugin for it.